# Perl assign array elements to hash user defined key

Tags: perl

Below is code in which I need help.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my @arrayElements = ('Array Functions');
print join(", ", @arrayElements);
### Output => Array Functions

my %hashElements = ();
```

I want to assign the content of `@arrayElements` to `$hashElements{Item}` 
Missing some core concepts or trying wrong and been a while struggling with this.

Comment: Your array has only one element. Please provide the expected hash layout.

Comment: Yes that's the only element in array.

Comment: `perl -w` has been obsolete since 2000. Please `use warnings;` instead.

Comment: Are you looking for [`perldoc perlreftut`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlreftut)?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Isn't it just `$hashElements{Item} = @arrayElements;`?

Comment: @Barmar no, that would assign `1` to `$hashElements{Item}` because it would evaluate the array in scalar context.

Comment: `$hashElements{Item} = \@arrayElements;`

Comment: @Barmar that would assign a _reference_ of `@arrayElements` to `$hashElements{Item}`. That means it's basically the whole data structure. If you print it, you'll get something like `ARRAY=0xD34DB33F`, and you'd have to use `$hashElements{Item}->[0]` to get to the actual string `'Array Functions'`.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be missing some core concepts of Perl (or programming in general). If you are learning Perl through a book or online tutorial, I suggest you re-read the chapters on arrays and hashes.

Let's look at the things involved here. You have:

- `@arrayElements`, which is an *array*. It contains a list with one elements, the string `'Array Functions'`.
- `%hashElements`, which is a *hash*. It's empty.
- `$hashElements{Item}`, which is a *scalar* value. You want to set this.

You say you want `$hashElements{Item}` to have the value `'Array Functions'`, which you have as the first element in your array `@arrayElements`.

```
$hashElements{Item} = $arrayElements[0];
```

And that's it. Both `$hashElements{Item}` and `$arrayElements[0]` are *scalar* values. That's why their *sigils* (the sign at the front) changes from an `@` (for array) or `%` (for hash) to a `$`. You can distinguish whether the value came from a hash or an array by the brackets used to access the elements. `[]` is for arrays, and `{}` is for hashes.

You cannot do the following though.

```
$hashElements{Item} = @arrayElements;
```

Because `$hashElements{Item}` is a scalar, the thing on the right hand side of the assignment will be treated in *scalar context*. An array in scalar context gets converted to the number of elements in the array, so this would assign `1`. That's not what you want.

You should really read up more about this, and also pick better names for your variables. Your example is very confusing. In general, we don't do `$CamelCase` for variable names in Perl, but instead use `$snake_case`, which is easier to read and type.

Take a look at the following resources to learn more about the concepts I've mentioned above.

[Perl Maven](https://perlmaven.com/perl-tutorial), [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html), [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: Thanks for the ... I understood the problem now with your comments.                   "An array in scalar context gets converted to the number of elements in the array, so this would assign 1. That's not what you want."                                                                           I was getting numer of elements and after reading this got the mistake which I was doing. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Shirinsh I'm glad I could help. Please take a moment to read [ask] and to learn what to do when someone answers your question. Thanks. :)